# How do I get the score to change in the game in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game in PyGame, but I can't get the score to change when a player gets three 'x's in a row. Whenever I run the code, the game starts, I can place 'x's and 'o's, I can clear the board, and close the window, but even if there is a winner, the score doesn't change. I want each "three in a row" to count as a point. I want the points counted, and when a player has five points, they win the whole game. I tried printing the score to the terminal, but those numbers are messed up after one win, but that shouldn't be a problem if you clear the board between rounds. I'm not getting any errors either, so I don't know where to start. I Googled how to fix this, but nothing made sense or fit this situation.

I don't have anything checking for whether or not the 'o's have won, but I'll just copy/paste the part with the 'x's and change a few things so it works for the 'o's as well.

I don't know what is wrong, so here is all of my code:

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
P_WIDTH, P_HEIGHT = 79, 80
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tic-Tac-Toe")

main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic sans", 40)
X_WINS = 0
O_WINS = 0
TIES = 0

BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Board3.jpg")).convert_alpha(), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
title_label1 = main_font.render("Tic-Tac-Toe", True, (0, 0, 0))
Player_1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("X.png")).convert_alpha(), (P_WIDTH, P_HEIGHT))
Player_2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("O.png")).convert_alpha(), (P_WIDTH, P_HEIGHT))
X_WINS_LABEL = main_font.render(f"X = {X_WINS}", True, (0, 0, 0))
O_WINS_LABEL = main_font.render(f"O = {O_WINS}", True, (0, 0, 0))
TIES_LABEL = main_font.render(f"Ties = {TIES}", True, (0, 0, 0))
X_WON_LABEL = main_font.render("WINNER: X", True, (0, 0, 0))
O_WON_LABEL = main_font.render("WINNER: O", True, (0, 0, 0))

board_state = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], ]


def redraw_window():
    global Player_1
    global board_state
    global TIES
    global X_WINS
    global X_WINS_LABEL
    global O_WINS_LABEL
    global TIES_LABEL

    WIN.blit(BG, (0, 0))
    WIN.blit(title_label1, (175, 20))
    WIN.blit(X_WINS_LABEL, (100, 450))
    WIN.blit(O_WINS_LABEL, (350, 450))
    WIN.blit(TIES_LABEL, (205, 450))

    y_cursor = 0
    for row in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30):
        x_cursor = 0
        for col in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30):
            if board_state[row][col] == 'x':
                WIN.blit(Player_1, (x_cursor, y_cursor))
            elif board_state[row][col] == 'o':
                WIN.blit(Player_2, (x_cursor, y_cursor))
            x_cursor += WIDTH // 31  # move the cursor across
        y_cursor += HEIGHT // 31  # move the cursor down

    pygame.display.update()


def main():

    while True:
        global X_WINS
        global O_WINS
        global TIES

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)
            elif event.type == pygame.locals.KEYDOWN:

                # Place an "X"
                if event.key == K_1:
                    board_state[7][7] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_2:
                    board_state[7][13] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_3:
                    board_state[7][19] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_4:
                    board_state[13][7] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_5:
                    board_state[13][13] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_6:
                    board_state[13][19] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_7:
                    board_state[19][7] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_8:
                    board_state[19][13] = 'x'
                if event.key == K_9:
                    board_state[19][19] = 'x'

                # Place an "O"
                if event.key == K_q:
                    board_state[7][7] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_w:
                    board_state[7][13] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_e:
                    board_state[7][19] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_a:
                    board_state[13][7] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_s:
                    board_state[13][13] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_d:
                    board_state[13][19] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_z:
                    board_state[19][7] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_x:
                    board_state[19][13] = 'o'
                if event.key == K_c:
                    board_state[19][19] = 'o'

                # Check for wins
                if board_state[7][7] == 'x' and board_state[7][13] == 'x' and board_state[7][19] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1
                if board_state[13][7] == 'x' and board_state[13][13] == 'x' and board_state[13][19] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1
                if board_state[19][7] == 'x' and board_state[19][13] == 'x' and board_state[19][19] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1
                if board_state[7][7] == 'x' and board_state[13][7] == 'x' and board_state[19][7] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1
                if board_state[7][13] == 'x' and board_state[13][13] == 'x' and board_state[19][13] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1
                if board_state[7][19] == 'x' and board_state[13][19] == 'x' and board_state[19][19] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1
                if board_state[7][7] == 'x' and board_state[13][13] == 'x' and board_state[19][19] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1
                if board_state[19][7] == 'x' and board_state[13][13] == 'x' and board_state[7][19] == 'x':
                    X_WINS += 1

                # Winning the game
                if X_WINS >= 5:
                    WIN.blit(X_WON_LABEL, (190, 175))
                if O_WINS >= 5:
                    WIN.blit(O_WON_LABEL, (190, 175))

                # Clear the board
                if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                    board_state[7][7], board_state[7][13], board_state[7][19], board_state[13][7], board_state[13][13], board_state[13][19], board_state[19][7], board_state[19][13], board_state[19][19] = 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none'

                # Clear the score
                if event.key == K_DELETE:
                    X_WINS, O_WINS, TIES = 0, 0, 0
        redraw_window()


main()
```

Comment: You create a surface called `X_WINS_LABEL` once, and only once, the contents of which never change. There's no magical relationship between `X_WINS` and `X_WINS_LABEL`. There's nothing that contractually binds `X_WINS_LABEL` to update when `X_WINS` does. Every time the score changes, you need to create and display another surface.

Comment: FYI, you could create an identical `board_state` with just one line, using list comprehension: `board_state = [[None for a in range(31)] for b in range(31)]`. Generally if you see a huge amount of repetition in your code, you probably could use a loop in most cases to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `X_WINS_LABEL` when the value of X_WINS changes, e.g.

```
X_WINS += 1
X_WINS_LABEL = main_font.render(f"X = {X_WINS}", True, (0, 0, 0))
```

As it is, `X_WINS_LABEL` is initialized with a value but never changed, updating `X_WINS` will not cause `X_WINS_LABEL` to update on its own.

You could also get rid of the `X_WINS_LABEL` var all together by generating the message when redrawing:

```
WIN.blit(main_font.render(f"X = {X_WINS}", True, (0, 0, 0)), (100, 450))
```

This would be a little cleaner in that you don't have to manage the win count and the label independently, but you will be calling `main_font.render` more frequently. Depending on how expensive rendering a message is, this may or may not be a worthwhile tradeoff.

Comment: I put "X_WINS_LABEL = main_font.render(f"X = {X_WINS}", True, (0, 0, 0))
" in all the if statments with X_WINS += 1, it counted the number of wins, but when I try to clear the board, it also adds a point to whomever just scored. Do you know anything to address this?

Comment: It looks like you're checking for the win condition on _every_ input, not just inputs where a player has made a move, so clearing the board (or making another move after a player has won) will increment the score as well. One way to handle this is to track if any player has won the round, only check for victory conditions of no player has won, and set the variable tracking the round win to false when clearing the board and true when a player wins.